# Connection Manager error (ORACLE) on SSIS Catalog deployed on server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

When deploying an SSIS package I get the following error:

[image]

This package works on my visual studio.  This might be a dumb question, but do I need to install something on the server where the SISS catalog is deployed?

I'm using a "Oracle Source" connection, which I think is the connection manager giving the issue.
the package is running in 64 bits (in 32 bits also fails with the same error)

it seems the error is that it doesn't recognise the connection manager

the package was developed in VisualStudio 2019 (with a target version 2019 in the properties)

My SQL server database is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2548.0 (X64) Jun 8 2015 11:08:03 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

and my Oracle db is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: If it works on your development client, but not on the deployed server than you must have something installed/configured on your client that is not on your server.  My guess would be some part of the Oracle client as folks often forget that these may need to be installed on the server(s) also.

Comment: yes, that is my thinking as well, hence my question, what would be the package that I should install on the server for oracle source. I couldn't find a particular one, I thought I might be the attunity, but I don't have that one on my local pc, I have attunity v3 and v4 on the server though

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15), but it looks like you will need to install Microsoft Connector for Oracle, the Oracle client and Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity, unless you are already on SS2019 or higher..

Comment: Hello barry, this was the solution, I had to change the version for the package to SQL server 2014 and then use the attunity V3 for it to work.  thank you for your time. if you want to pop this as a response I can approve it as one :)  (not that you need the points eheh)  anyway, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks, good to know.